# How to get the "text" from textbox using a binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

How do I get the content/text from a textbox using a binding? My textbox looks like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtFields" Text="" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         Background="#FFCBEECD" AcceptsReturn="True" >
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding AddFieldCommand}"></KeyBinding>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

As seen, I would like to receive the content/text from the textbox, when the user hits the enter-button.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a property and bind it to your `TextBox.Text`, something like:

ViewModel:

```
public string TextProperty {get; set;}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtFields" Text="{Binding TextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}".../>
```

And then you can access it (`TextProperty`) from the `AddFieldCommand` command.

Comment: @MikaelKP, just define a property in your VM, where you have defined the `AddFieldCommand`, and use that to bind to the Text. I have updated my answer.

Comment: How do I exactly access the property? I have created a Text="{Binding Text}" property, but I cannot quite see how I get access to it.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work. I have the following content in my XAML:   `<TextBox x:Name="txtMethods" Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding MethodsTextProperty}" Background="#FFCBEECD" AcceptsReturn="False">
                    <TextBox.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding AddMethodCommand}"></KeyBinding>
                    </TextBox.InputBindings>
                </TextBox>`   I have the following property in ViewModel: `public string MethodsTextProperty { get; set; }`  Tested by `Console.WriteLine(MethodsTextProperty);` in the method

Comment: @MikaelKP, what part is not working? When you use `Console.WriteLine(MethodsTextProperty);` what did you get? have you checked the Output panel? Please note, the default `UpdateSourceTrigger` is set to `LostFocus`, you may want change that to `PropertyChanged` (edited XAML above)

Comment: I get nothing in the Output Panel from `Console.WriteLine(MethodsTextProperty)`, when I type something in the textbox and hit the enter-button.

Comment: @MikaelKP, Add this into your binding: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

Comment: Still no luck.. But where exists some Binding errors: `BindingExpression path error: 'FieldsTextProperty' property not found on 'object' ''ClassData'. BindingExpression:Path=FieldsTextProperty; DataItem='ClassData'; target element is 'TextBox' (Name='txtFields'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')` and `BindingExpression path error: 'AddFieldCommand' property not found on 'object' ''ClassData'. BindingExpression:Path=AddFieldCommand; DataItem='ClassData'; target element is 'KeyBinding'; target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')`

Comment: You will either have to add the TextProperty to the ClassData class or you will need to adjust your binding path in the xaml.

Comment: @MikaelKP, it looks like you are missing basic knowledge of the databinding. Please start from looking at some tutorial of what DataBinding is about: e.g. [http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/).